# create json file with loop for list of artifacts python

Tags: python, json

I have a list of many files (artifacts) in the list variable. (Here I  just shortened this list to 4 elements).

```
print(type(file_list))
<class 'list'>
print(file_list)
['file_AA.txt', 'file_BB.txt', 'file_CC.txt', 'file_DD.txt']
```

I create json dictionary with python like this:

```
dictionary={
   "instrument" : instrument,
   "artifacts" : {
       "metadata" : metadata,
       "product_file" : product_file,
       "raw_fileAA": fileAA.txt},
   "schema" : "scene.v1.json"}
```

Then I save it like this:

```
json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 4)
with open(scene_out, "w") as outfile:    
  outfile.write(json_object)
```

But I don't know how to use the 'for' loop to put whole file_list in "artifacts" list inside dictionary. I want to obtain something like this:

```
dictionary={
   "instrument" : instrument,
   "artifacts" : {
       "metadata" : metadata,
       "product_file" : product_file,
       "raw_fileAA": fileAA.txt},
       "raw_fileBB": fileBB.txt},
       "raw_fileCC": fileCC.txt},
       "raw_fileDD": fileDD.txt},
   "schema" : "scene.v1.json"}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is the value `fileAA.txt` ? A string, the file content ?

Comment: is just a list element (files in my folder). I create it like this: file_list = glob.glob(pattern)

Comment: That's not what I asked. In your result dictionnary, what is the value of key `raw_fileAA` ? Because it doesn't have quotes in your post, so it seems to be a variable, not a string

Comment: They are strings - just file names

Answer (score 0):

`(key, values)` needs to be added in `dictionary['artifacts']`

```py
dictionary={
   "instrument" : 'instrument',
   "artifacts" : {
       "metadata" : 'metadata',
       "product_file" : 'product_file',
       "raw_fileAA": 'fileAA.txt'},
   "schema" : "scene.v1.json"}

l = ['file_AA.txt', 'file_BB.txt', 'file_CC.txt', 'file_DD.txt']

for i in l:
    dictionary['artifacts']['raw_' + i.split('.')[0].replace('_', '')] = i
```

```
{'instrument': 'instrument',
 'artifacts': {'metadata': 'metadata',
  'product_file': 'product_file',
  'raw_fileAA': 'file_AA.txt',
  'raw_fileBB': 'file_BB.txt',
  'raw_fileCC': 'file_CC.txt',
  'raw_fileDD': 'file_DD.txt'},
 'schema': 'scene.v1.json'}
```

Comment: Thank you Epsi95 let me just play with your answer. I have to put it inside my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the artifacts dictionary like this.

```
file_list = ['file_AA.txt', 'file_BB.txt', 'file_CC.txt', 'file_DD.txt']

artifacts_dict = {'metadata': metadata, 'product_file': product_file }

artifacts_dict.update({'raw_'+file.replace('.txt',''):file for file in file_list})
```

Then use that when creating the json dictionary.

```
dictionary={
   "instrument" : instrument,
   "artifacts" : artifacts_dict,
   "schema" : "scene.v1.json"}
```

Comment: Wow that's brilliant. Thank you norie!

Comment: And how to change this if I would like to have:
raw_file1: file_AA.txt 
raw_file2: file_BB.txt
raw_file3: file_CC.txt
raw_file4: file_DD.txt

Comment: artifacts_dict.update({'raw_file'+str(i):file for i,file in enumerate(file_list)})
I don't know how this works but it is.. ;) This double 'for' loop is a mystery for me. Maybe someone could explain this?

Comment: That isn't a 'double' for loop, using enumerate on an iterable object returns both a counter (i) and the enumerate object (file).